# Unable to download PDF at the mobile but when page open at desktop version PDF open

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ruby

1----->   not work

```
function DownloadFile(){
   var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = 'http://images.railyatri.in/invoices/ticket_4_44237567_25559827.pdf';
link.download = 'http://images.railyatri.in/invoices/ticket_4_44237567_25559827.pdf';
            link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));}
```

2-->  not work at mobile (also desktop mobile version [devtool]) but working for desktop

```
window. location.href="http://images.railyatri.in/invoices/ticket_4_44237567_25559827.pdf";
```

3--->   not work at mobile (but working for desktop mobile version [devtool] pdf open at new tab) but working for desktop

```
window.open("http://images.railyatri.in/invoices/ticket_4_44237567_25559827.pdf');
```

Comment: @KJ The PDF is generated dynamically

Comment: @kj thanks for attending to my issue.  in the PDF, every user has different data, in the pdf URL  user_booking_id=44237567  PNR_num=25559827, these 2 things are different for every user.   the issue only occurring at the mobile device

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419719/unable-to-download-pdf-file-showing-page-layout-may-be-unexpected-due-to-quirks  -->>  also this issue related with

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419720/why-doctype-html-is-missing-already-html-file-include-with-doctype-html-th   -->>>>also this issue related with

Answer (score 0):

```
  <a class="button_type_2" href="https://images.railyatri.in/invoices/ticket_4_<%=data['user_id']%>_<%=data['id']%>.pdf"  download="https://images.railyatri.in/invoices/ticket_4_<%=data['user_id']%>_<%=data['id']%>.pdf">Download Ticket</a>
```

use HTTPS instead of HTTP

Comment: all code added above is working.